# Split lines without omitting empty lines in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string

How can I split lines in Swift (4+) without omitting the empty rows?

Both `"1\n2\n\n3".split { $0.isNewline }` and `"1\n2\n\n3".split(separator: "\n")` give me only three items while I need 4 with the third one beiing empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
"1\n2\n\n3".components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

Or more concise and readable, as suggested by [Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275053/split-lines-without-omitting-empty-lines-in-swift/57275175?noredirect=1#comment101049150_57275175):

```
"1\n2\n\n3".components(separatedBy: .newlines)
```

These both result in: ["1", "2", "", "3"]

Comment: or `components(separatedBy: .newlines)`

Answer (score 6):

`split` has `omittingEmptySubsequences` parameter just for that.

By default it's `true`. So just set it to `false`:

```
"1\n2\n\n3".split(omittingEmptySubsequences: false) { $0.isNewline }
```